# Is there a R function that parse block sections of an ASCI file only?

Tags: r, parsing, text-files

I have a text file made like this:

```
4 -- Elmo857 Jaskolski867 (10 y/o M) Brockton, Massachusetts

VITAL SIGNS

  * Creatinine Ratio =  13.06
  *                   Glucose =  65.38
  *                    Height = 144.60

-----
3 -- Lan153 Kris249 (14 y/o F) South Hadley, Massachusetts 

VITAL SIGNS

  * Creatinine Ratio =   0.79
  *                   Glucose =  67.06
  *                    Height = 156.80

-----
```

I need to parse it within R to generate a dataframe like this

```
ID Name                Age Gender Location                  Creatinine Ratio Glucose Height

4  Elmo857Jaskolski867 10  M      Brockton,Massachusetts    13.06          65.38   144.6

3  Lan153Kris249       14  F      SouthHadley,Massachusetts 0.79           67.06   156.8
```

There are already answers dealing with specific parsing request, but I could not find any dealing with block parsing (each probands is limited by "-----".
Any pointer for me?

Comment: You can create a connection to the file with `f=file()`; then `readLines(f,n=1)` will read one line at a time. You can use this to read line-by-line, stopping each time you reach the next `-----`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward with the `tidyverse`...

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- text %>%               #assumes your text is a single character string
  str_split("-----") %>%     #split at -----
  unlist() %>%               #unlist
  str_trim() %>%             #trim spaces
  enframe(name = NULL) %>%   #convert to dataframe (tibble) - one column called value
  mutate(ID = str_extract(value, "^\\d+"),                          #first digits
         Name = str_trim(str_match(value, "-- (.+?) \\(")[,2]),     #between -- and (
         Age = as.numeric(str_match(value, "\\((\\d+)")[,2]),       #digits after (
         Gender = str_match(value, "(M|F)\\)")[,2],                 #MF before )
         Location = str_trim(str_match(value, "\\) (.+?)\\n")[,2]), #after ) to end line
         Creat = as.numeric(str_match(value, "Ratio =\\s+([\\.0-9]+)")[,2]),
         Glucose = as.numeric(str_match(value, "Glucose =\\s+([\\.0-9]+)")[,2]),
         Height = as.numeric(str_match(value, "Height =\\s+([\\.0-9]+)")[,2])) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(ID)) %>%     #remove final blank row
  select(-value)             #remove original text

df

  ID    Name                   Age Gender Location                    Creat Glucose Height

1 4     Elmo857 Jaskolski867    10 M      Brockton, Massachusetts     13.1     65.4   145.
2 3     Lan153 Kris249          14 F      South Hadley, Massachusetts  0.79    67.1   157.
```